# Scraping a table from a website Screener.in using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am using the below code to get the table but it notice there is one + button with data and not getting on excel, as inspect the data show after clicking on + button

please help to get the all table data include the + button column

```
Sub get_table()

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://www.screener.in/company/COFORGE/consolidated/"
    
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url
    
    Do While ie.Busy = True: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    
    Dim tbl As HTMLTable
    Set tbl = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(1)
    Dim trcounter As Integer
    Dim tdcounter As Integer
    
    trcounter = 1
    tdcounter = 1
    thcounter = 1
    
    Dim tr As HTMLTableRow
    Dim td As HTMLTableCell
    Dim th As HTMLTableRow
    
    Dim mySH As Worksheet
    Set mySH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    
    ' this for date
    For Each th In tbl.getElementsByTagName("th")
            mySH.Cells(tdcounter, thcounter).Value = th.innerText
            thcounter = thcounter + 1
        Next th
        
    ' this for table data
    For Each tr In tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            mySH.Cells(trcounter, tdcounter).Value = td.innerText
            tdcounter = tdcounter + 1
        Next td
        tdcounter = 1
        trcounter = trcounter + 1
    Next tr

End Sub
```

Comment: You tried to link to an image, but there was no image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first check if the `<td>` contains + button using [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function), if so then click the + button. After clicking all the + button in the table, you can read the data and write them into the sheet.

The working example is like this:

```
Sub LOADIE()
    Set ieA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieA.Visible = True
    ieA.navigate "https://www.screener.in/company/COFORGE/consolidated/"
    Do Until ieA.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set doc = ieA.document
    Set tbl = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")(1)

    trcounter = 1
    tdcounter = 1
    thcounter = 1
    
    Dim tr As HTMLTableRow
    Dim td As HTMLTableCell
    Dim th As HTMLTableRow
    
    Dim mySH As Worksheet
    Set mySH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    
    ' this for date
    For Each th In tbl.getElementsByTagName("th")
        mySH.Cells(tdcounter, thcounter).Value = th.innerText
        thcounter = thcounter + 1
    Next th
        
    ' this for clicking the + button
    For Each tr In tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
        If InStr(td.innerHTML, "button") > 0 Then
            td.getElementsByTagName("button")(0).Click
        End If
        Next td
        tdcounter = 1
        trcounter = trcounter + 1
    Next tr

    ' this for table data
    trcounter = 1
    For Each tr In tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            mySH.Cells(trcounter, tdcounter).Value = td.innerText
            tdcounter = tdcounter + 1
        Next td
        tdcounter = 1
        trcounter = trcounter + 1
    Next tr

   ieA.Quit
   Set ieA = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: now i am facing other issue the + sign content some time shows some time not please can help